# How to Update NSManagedObject subclass when a to-many related NSManagedObject subclass changes?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to maintain the correct emoAvg in "Day". Here's what I'm looking accomplish:

1. update the emoAvg of "Day" whenever a "Emotion" is related to
   "Day"...a day can have many emotions.
2. update the emoAvg of "Day" whenever an "Emotion" is removed from "Day"
3. update the emoAvg of "Day" whenever a the emotion property of "Emotion" changes.

[image]

I want to keep all this code in the model layer and I have been able to connect emotions with days by calling the following code which attaches a Day to an emotion when an emotion is created.

I have not been able to write the custom accessors for the to-many relationship that "Day" has with "Emotion." I'm stuck at Xcode 4.6.2 and the copy/paste custome ObjectiveC accessors functions doesn't seem to exist in this version.

What's a good way to build this code?

```
 - (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:date forKey:@"date"];

    [self associateDay];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];

}

-(void)associateDay
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:self.date];

    //Start of Day
    [dateComponents setHour:0];
    [dateComponents setMinute:0];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0];
    NSDate *startOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    //NSLog(@"Start of Day:       %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startOfDay]);

    //End of Day
    [dateComponents setHour:23];
    [dateComponents setMinute:59];
    [dateComponents setSecond:59];
    NSDate *endOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    //NSLog(@"End of Day:         %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endOfDay]);

    //Find all Day Entities that fall on the same calendar date
    NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@ AND date < %@", startOfDay, endOfDay];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchDays = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Day"];
    fetchDays.predicate = datePredicate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(id)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSArray *daysFound = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchDays error:nil];

    if ([daysFound count] == 1)
    {
        Day *dayWithMatchingDate = [daysFound objectAtIndex:0];
        self.day = dayWithMatchingDate;
        NSLog(@"Found %d matching days",[daysFound count]);
    }

    if ([daysFound count] > 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found %d matching days...Something needs fixing",[daysFound count]);
    }

    if ([daysFound count] < 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found %d matching days...Making a new Day and associating it",[daysFound count]);
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(id)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
        Day *newDay = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        newDay.date = self.date;
        self.day = newDay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not necessarily a good idea to model the `Day` as part of the data model. The existing date attribute should be sufficient for selection, filtering and other logic.

Nevertheless, you are on the right track. The key is to override the setters. You need to override the following setters in `Emotion` and `Day` (my tip: create a *category* on emotion `Emotion+Additions` to keep this code separated from the basic model classes).

1. `setEmotion` in `Emotion`
2. `removeEmotionsObject` in `Day`
3. `addEmotionsObject` in `Day`

e.g.

```
-(void)removeEmotionsObject:(Emotion)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" 
        withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveEmotions] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" 
        withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
}
```

More details on these accessors in the [relevant section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW6) of the Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: Mundi, thanks for the response. I read the section you linked prior to asking the question. Can you explain the "[[self primitiveEmotions] removeObject:value];" I'm not clear on where that code comes from.

Comment: Every managed object `attribute` is backed by methods like `setPrimitiveAttribute` etc. automatically. `removeObject` is a regular `NSSet` instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code I asked for working.
However it is a tangled mess and I think it's better to work with NSNotificationCenter and observe changes to the relevant objects.
Here's the code that worked.
Gotta give props to Mundi for helping me out.

```
- (void)addEmotionsObject:(Emotion *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

    [[self primitiveEmotions] addObject:value];

    [self calculateEmotionalAverage];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
}

- (void)removeEmotionsObject:(Emotion *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];

    [[self primitiveEmotions] removeObject:value];

    [self calculateEmotionalAverage];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
}



- (void)addEmotions:(NSSet *)value
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];

    [[self primitiveEmotions] unionSet:value];

    [self calculateEmotionalAverage];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}



- (void)removeEmotions:(NSSet *)value
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];

    [[self primitiveEmotions] minusSet:value];

    [self calculateEmotionalAverage];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"emotions" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}


-(void)calculateEmotionalAverage
{
    float emotionalTotal = 0;
    for (Emotion *emo in self.emotions)
    {
        if ([emo.emotion isEqualToString:@"Joy = 22"]){
            emotionalTotal += 22.0;
        }
        NSLog(@"%f",emotionalTotal);
    }
}
```